# memory inefficiencies in row/col slicing scipy.sparse.csc_matrix

Tags: python, memory, scipy, slice, sparse-matrix

Slicing a scipy.sparse.csc_matrix by rows/cols using the below code leads to ~doubling of memory allocation upon slicing. How to slice in place while avoiding this increment in memory during slicing?

```
import numpy
from scipy import sparse

@profile
def slice_matrix(n=10000):
    a = sparse.csc_matrix(numpy.random.random((n,n))>0.9, dtype=float)
    mask = numpy.repeat(numpy.random.choice([True, False]), n)
    return a[mask, ][:, mask]
```

Comment: Scipy.sparse matrices (at least in the csr/csc format) perform indexing like this with a matrix product.  They construct an 'extractor' matrix from the indexing `E`, and do `M.dot(E)` to return a new matrix.  If you want to avoid that you need to construct a new set of `indptr, indices, data` from the original attributes and your indexing pattern.

Comment: Yes, many thanks, that's what I would like to do. Any suggestions on how to systematically infer these (esp. `indptr`) for given matrix `a` and `numpy.where(mask)[0]`?

Comment: Row selection with the `lil` format can spase efficient.  It's even `view` like.

Comment: If it was easy and fast the devs would have done it already

Comment: Yes, all solutions I have come across so far are either memory inefficient (multiplication with extractor matrix) or slow.